# I am getting this error while running my gattling code [at io.gatling.http.protocol.HttpProtocol$.apply(HttpProtocol.scala:71)]

Tags: gatling

import io.gatling.core.Predef._

import io.gatling.http.Predef._

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class Simulations extends Simulation {

def test(){

val httpConf = http

```
.baseURL("http://computer-database.gatling.io")

.acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")

.doNotTrackHeader("1")

.acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")

.acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")

.userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")
```

val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation")

```
.exec(http("request_1")

.get("/"))

.pause(5)
```

setUp(

```
scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpConf))
```

}}

object Demo {

def main(args: Array[String]) {

val pt = new Simulations

pt.test()

}

}

Comment: I am not sure what you are running your code with but this works fine for me after I strip out `object Demo` and remove `def Test()`. I am using IntelliJ to run my tests. If you are using IntelliJ as well I can post my code up as an answer for you.

Comment: I am using eclipse and in that i have maven with scala plugin.

Comment: Also, please share your code too.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, my code. This runs fine in IntelliJ. I've no experience with eclipse so I can't help you on that front.

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

class SimulationAmritPalSingh extends Simulation {
    val httpConf = http
      .baseURL("http://computer-database.gatling.io")
      .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
      .doNotTrackHeader("1")
      .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
      .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
      .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")

    val scn = scenario("BasicSimulation")
      .exec(http("request_1")
      .get("/"))
      .pause(5)

    setUp(
      scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))
        .protocols(httpConf))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have one more doubt regading scala  which is like in java we can not run any java class without main function is that same in scala too,because the code you have sent me doesnt have main method and when i try to run this code ,it doesnot run in eclipse thats why my above code has method def test() and Object Demo ,which is calling that method.

Comment: Like I said I don't know how it works in eclipse. In IntelliJ you pull down the gatling library using Maven and it will automatically find the simulations and offer you a choice. The guide on how to set up the project is [here](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2.3/extensions/maven_archetype.html), in their docs. I imagine there is an entry point to the program in there that scans the compiled files.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have almost solve all the errors.

Comment: ALso i need little bit more help of yours which is          -                              While running my simulation via engine.scala , its not going forward its just stick upto below mention .
Select simulation id (default is 'basicsimulation'). Accepted characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, - and _
BUT while running from maven install its excuting fine.Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Sure! It's very simple. You just need to press enter / return two times and wait. It is only waiting for input. Once you start the simulation you enter a number and press return. Then you will see `Select simulation id..` - press enter, `Select run description...` - press enter and wait.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you're happy with the answer could you mark this as resolved? Might help others in the future.